# Convert date time format?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert date time in `12/20/2013 17:40`  format to the below format

`20 Dec 2013 05:40 pm`. How it's possible?

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you want to keep it as a Datetime or a string?

Comment: You don't convert it, you just format it to a string differently.

Comment: Btw. a `DateTime` itself does *not* have any format at all. It's basically a nicely dressed `Int64`. Some `string`s only *represent* a `DateTime` in a certain format.

Comment: I need to keep it in a string

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This should do it

```
string originalDate = "2/20/2013 17:40";
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(originalDate, "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
     string requiredFormat = parsedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm ttt");
}
```

OutPut:

```
20 Feb 2013 05:40 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mydatetime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**  if you have datetime in `String` format

```
String str = "12/20/2013 17:40";//20 Dec 2013 05:40 pm
DateTime result;
string date="";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
date=result.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

**Method 2:**  if you have datetime in `DateTime` variable.

```
String strdatetime=datetime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use format strings:

this is from 1 minute google:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `DateTime` doesn't have a *format*, strings have..

If your `12/20/2013 17:40` is a `DateTime`, you can use [`DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to format it like;

```
date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your `12/20/2013 17:40` is a `string`, then you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "12/20/2013 17:40";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output will be;

```
20 Dec 2013 05:40 PM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/N4RnGU)</kbd>.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In `C# 6.0` you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/csharp-six#String-Interpolation) in order to display formatted dates.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("12/20/2013 17:40");
string formattedDate = $"{date: dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt}";
```